# How to query documents containing array of objects in Firestore collection using whereArrayContains() filter on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in firestore where each document contains an array of contacts and I want to query those documents where any contact's email id is a certain value.

I came across whereArrayContains() filter at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#whereArrayContains(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object), with the following description:-

> **public Query whereArrayContains (String field, Object value)** 
>   
> Creates and returns a new Query with the additional filter that documents must
>   contain the specified field, the value must be an array, and that the
>   array must contain the provided value.
>
> A Query can have only one whereArrayContains() filter.

Can the `value` in the above method point to a field inside an object for an array of objects?

Also, the phrase `the value must be an array` is a little confusing given the method parameter is also called `value`. I am sure the documentation means that the `field` should be present in the document and **its value** should be an array and that the array should contain the `value` parameter.

Comment: What do you mean through `an object for an array of objects`? Please also post your database structure.

Comment: In each document I have a group of contacts. One example of a document would be {groupName:'group1', contacts: [{name: 'Abc', email:'abc@abc.com'}, {name:'Def', email:'def@abc.com'}]}. Now my aim is to fetch all groups where contacts array contains the email 'abc@abc.com'. Is it possible to do this using array-contains operator?

Comment: It might work but please add a screenshot of your database structure to see it more clearly.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You cannot query fields of objects in arrays in a Firestore query. The array-contains query will instead compare with the objects in an array.

> the value must be an array

This refers to the value of the field you are trying to query against. Better phrasing for this would be

> Creates and returns a new Query with the additional filter that documents must contain the specified field, the value *of the specified field* must be an array, and that the array must contain the provided value.

If you are trying to filter for a user ID or something similar, consider adding a second array to the object you are querying, then adding the IDs as strings to that array:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "users": [someUserObject, someOtherUserObject],
    "userIds": ["someId", "someOtherId"]
}
```

then query that array instead:

```java
someRef.whereArrayContains("userIds", someId);
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/54081799, which has an answer showing how to do an `array-contains` with objects (which requires the entire object to be specified).

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the field point to the array and value means the String you want to check is present in array or not.

> You can use the array_contains operator to filter based on array
>   values. For example:

```
CollectionReference citiesRef = db.collection("cities");
citiesRef.whereArrayContains("regions", "west_coast");
```

> This query returns every city document where the regions field is an
>   array that contains west_coast. If the array has multiple instances of
>   the value you query on, the document is included in the results only
>   once.

The data is added as:-

```
CollectionReference cities = db.collection("cities");

Map<String, Object> data1 = new HashMap<>();
data1.put("name", "San Francisco");
data1.put("state", "CA");
data1.put("country", "USA");
data1.put("capital", false);
data1.put("population", 860000);
data1.put("regions", Arrays.asList("west_coast", "norcal"));
cities.document("SF").set(data1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it's not possible to do what you ask.

The "Firebase-y" way to do what you want, is to create a sub-collection rather than an array, and then each object in the array is instead a document in the sub collection.

You can then query the individual field in the sub-collection using collection-group queries.

If you need access to the parent document, you'll can access it by calling

```
snapshot.document.parent.parent
```

which returns a DocumentReference. (The parent of the document is a collection, so its .parent.parent to get the parent document). You'll then have to re-query for that reference.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two arrays like the accepted answer, you can use map instead, structure your data like this:

```json
{
    users: {
        userId1: {
            name: "...",
            //rest of the fields
        },
        userId2: {
            name: "...",
            //rest of the fields
        }
    }
    //rest of the fields
}
```

Then use this query to filter by an id

```kotlin
collectionRef.orderBy("users.userId1")
```