# How to query an array of objects contains a field value firebase angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following document:

```
"players" : [ 
  {
    "id" : userid,
    "name" : "dissident"
  }, 
  {
    "teamId" : teamId,
    "name" : "ink"
  }
]
```

This is what I tried, but it is not working

```
this.afs.collection('matches', ref => ref.where('players', 'array-contains', {teamId: teamId}))
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more on it what is your expected output?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Mridul Im trying to get this document only if the players array contains the given team id

Comment: Are you referring JSON as document? and you want to return the whole object if teamid matches with given team id?

Comment: ERROR FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field teamId)

Comment: @Mridul yes if it matches with the given team id

Comment: Is players document is single object or array of object?

Comment: @Chellappanவ players is an array of objects.

Comment: Try this this.afs.collection('matches', ref => ref.where('players', 'array-contains', "teamId"))

Comment: @Chellappanவ tried boss not working

Comment: are you getting same error?

Comment: No I'm not getting the data

Comment: You may be interested by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54081799/firestore-to-query-by-an-arrays-field-value/54082731#54082731 which explains that it is not possible, with array-contains, to query for a specific property of an object stored in an array

Answer (score 1):

Your error is this:

> FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field teamId)

This means you passed an invalid value of `undefined` for `teamId` in the query, which is invalid.  You should debug your code and figure out why `teamId` is undefined, then fix that.

Comment: I even tried hardcoding the id to get the data it is not working

Comment: That sounds like a different problem than the one you first posted.  Maybe ask another question if it's different by nature?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
this.afs.collection('matches', ref => ref.where('players', 'array-contains', {teamId: teamId}))
```

to

```
this.afs.collection('matches', ref => ref.where('players', 'array-contains', {teamId: teamId, name : 'ink'}))
```

As you can see, this is actually possible **only** if you query for the entire object. But be aware, as Doug Stevenson mentioned in his answer if you pass an invalid value of undefined for `teamId` or for `name`, you'll always get the error that you are talking about.