# how to query nested maps inside an array field in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have structured my data in Firebase such that I have a collection of 'users' and each user has various fields as well as a 'skillsIndustry' Array field which contain Maps items (that have fields 'experience' and 'industry').

[image]

Now I would like to query my collection of users so that I can ask for all users that have worked in 'Airlines' with experience code of >= 1

Is this possible at all?  Or do I have to create sub collections and then use Collection Group Queries?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You can use `array-contains` to query for the entire object, as explained in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54082731/3371862), but not to query with `>` or `<.`

You could create a subcollection, but you can probably find a solution based on the duplication of the data in the same document, which is a common approach in the NoSQL world.

For example, you could have some extra fields named `airlinesExperience`, `shippingExperience`, etc. Then you use the `skillsIndustry` Array field when you want to display all the skills and years of experience, but you use the `xxxExperience` fields when you want to query.

---

Another possibility would be to use a map of key/value pairs like

```
key = "Airlines" / value = 1

key = "Shipping" / value = 3
```

Then you can query with:

```
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .where('skillsIndustry.Shipping', '>', 2)
```

Comment: Some additional info to add to this: If you ever want to query "users who have **no** shipping experience", you would need to store a value of `0` for `skillsIndustry.Shipping` because if a field in a document doesn't have a value, it won't be added to its index. If `1`/`2`/`3` correspond to some enum (such as `little experience`, `some experience`, and so on) you should space out the values some more and use `10`/`20`/`30` (commonly larger like `100`/`200`/`300`/etc) which gives you the flexibility to insert new levels without having to rewrite every document in your database.