# How can I order by an array element with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this firebase document, and I want to order by the text field from the first element of the name array, so the official name.

[image]

Here is the code I am trying to use, but it's not working:

```
get(collectionName: string): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.afs.collection(collectionName, ref => {
      let query: CollectionReference | Query = ref;
      query = query.orderBy('text', 'asc').where('name', 'array-contains', 'official');
      return query;
    }).valueChanges() as Observable<T[]>;
}
```

Comment: Did you enabled the indexing for that specific query ?

Comment: Cause as I can see you are using commpund queries here (multiple queries in your case 2 queries and that is, orderBy and where)

Comment: To be more specific, your query is getting you the expected result and not ordering or simply not getting any results? I ask this because I believe the query you are trying to make is not possible with Firestore.

Comment: I don't get any results, and I don't even know if I need the where. All I want to do is order by the name[0].text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying and sorting by object values inside arrays is not possible with Firestore, at least not directly, as you can see in this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54081889/12857703):

> The `array-contains` operations checks if an array contains a specific (complete) value. It can't check if an array of objects, contains an item with a specific value for a property.

The same applies to `orderBy`. So in order to do that you are going to need to change your Firestore structure, a possibility is to create a separate non array field that holds the value where the query should be sorted/queryied by, you can also create a subcollection to represent the values of the array, but that is for you to decide depending on your structure.