# Flutter Firestore query by arrayContains returns nothing even though document is clearly present and accessible

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I get an object directly from a collection in firestore it works just fine, although when I query for it using the where command nothing appears. I'm wonder if I'm incorrectly using the API or there is a bug

```dart
 await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('games')
        .where('status', arrayContains: 'GameStatus.uninitialized')
        .get()
        .then((value) => {
              if (value.docs.isNotEmpty)
                {
                  print(value.docs[0].reference.id),
                }
              else
                {
                  print('nada'),
                }
          
            });
```

[image]

Here is the firestore:
[image: firestore]

Answer (score 0):

arrayContains parameter takes string not list it should look like this

```
 await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('games')
            .where('status', arrayContains: 'GameStatus.uninitialized')
            .get()
            .then((value) => {
                  if (value.docs.isNotEmpty)
                    {
                      print(value.docs[0].reference.id),
                    }
                  else
                    {
                      print('nada'),
                    }
              
                });
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! Using a list or an object made no difference! I settled for just using isEquals for now, although this still really bugs me. Let me update the original post to clear up any confusion

Comment: can you post the firestore document screenshot  i want to see what kind of data you are trying to retrieve its hard to see on the jif

Comment: Just added it to the original post

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query firestore like that,
I will refer you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54081799/firestore-to-query-by-an-arrays-field-value)

Instead, try to put status in the root of document and then query it like this

```
 await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('games')
        .where('status', isEqualTo: 'GameStatus.uninitialized')
        .get()
        .then((value) => {
              if (value.docs.isNotEmpty)
                {
                  print(value.docs[0].reference.id),
                }
              else
                {
                  print('nada'),
                }
          
            });
```

Comment: Status is already at the root of the document 

Answer (score 0):

status field is not a type of array you can only use arrayContains for arrays
instead you should use likethis

```
 await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('games')
                .where('status', isEqualTo: 'GameStatus.uninitialized')
                .get()
                .then((value) => {
                      if (value.docs.isNotEmpty)
                        {
                          print(value.docs[0].reference.id),
                        }
                      else
                        {
                          print('nada'),
                        }
                  
                    });
```

or if you trying to query players field You currently can't build a query that looks for an object field within an array but you can use for string or integer like this

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('games')
                .where('players', arrayContains: 'GameStatus.uninitialized')
                .get()
                .then((value) => {
                      if (value.docs.isNotEmpty)
                        {
                          print(value.docs[0].reference.id),
                        }
                      else
                        {
                          print('nada'),
                        }
                  
                    });
```

Comment: Status field is a string, which is an array of characters, no? The documentation instructed this approach of querying strings in a document.

Comment: no unfortunately the are not the same! if that's your goal change Status field data type into an array and assign the characters for each indexes

Comment: From what I understand, I can only search top level, not nested arrays, and I'm looking just to get the field at the top (like status, or id) with a partial piece of the name