# Firestore apply Where to array in GO

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

I have these structs

```golang
type Notification struct {
    Content []NotificationContent `json:"content"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"createdAt"`
}

type NotificationContent struct {
    Language string `json:"language"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
}
```

And I'm trying to query my Firestore database to fetch any notification that have a specific `Language`.

Using

```golang
query := client.Collection("notifications").Where("Content.Language", "==", "en")
```

or

```golang
query := client.Collection("notifications").Where("Content.Language", "in", [1]string{"en"})
```

always return null.

Using nodejs I could also use

```js
client.Collection("notifications").where("Content", "array-contains", { Language: "en" })
```

but I have no idea how to translate to GO

Thanks for any input!

**EDIT**
Data structure and sample data as requested

[image: Data structure and sample data]

Comment: Could you please share your Firestore data structure? Also, could you please share a sample of your data used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54081889/13171940):

> The `array-contains` operations check if an array contains a specific (complete) value. It can't check if an array of objects contains an item with a specific value for a property.

Therefore, that is why the query you are trying to do won't work.

---

From the test I have made, the following query

```golang
query := client.Collection("notifications").Where("Content", "array-contains", map[string]string{"Language":"en"}).Documents(ctx)
```

will return no values, as the `array-contains` filter is looking for an entire object. But a similar query (workaround) is possible as shown on this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54082731/13171940):

> However, there is a possible workaround: it is actually possible to query for **the entire object**

In your case, the query would be as follows:

```golang
query := client.Collection("notifications").Where("Content", "array-contains", map[string]string{"Language":"en", "Title":"Foo Bar"}).Documents(ctx)
```

As you can see in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54081799/firestore-to-query-by-an-arrays-field-value), the data structure is similar to yours and the case of use is the same as yours. So, the recommendation made in this answer would fit your problem:

> The only way to do your query, is to add an additional field to your document with just the value you want to query existence on. So for example: `partyMemberNames: ["John Travolta", "Olivia Newton"]`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the answer for now. Thanks @rogelio-monter