# Firebase Query with where

Tags: flutter, firebase

How can I do query with where in firebase? For example I want to access to the nameL of locationEvent in the estructure of the photo.

I am using flutter to code my app.

[image: firebase photo]

Comment: Firebase has 20 products, including 2 NoSQL databases. Which product are you using here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries), you can do as follows:

```
// Create a reference to the collection
final collectionRef = db.collection('collectionName');

// Create a query against the collection.
final query = collectionRef.where('locationEvent.${nameL}', isEqualTo: 'jkn');

// Execute the query
query.get().then(
  (res) => print("Successfully completed"),
  onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"),
);
```

Comment: But How can I do it if locationEvent is now an array with diferents locations?
locationEvent=[{latitude:510,longitude:152,nameL:nameLocation},{latitude:5102,longitude:1522,nameL:nameLocation2}]

Comment: **This is a totally different case: behaviour for Maps and Arrays is different.** See this SO question/answer for an Array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54081799/firestore-to-query-by-an-arrays-field-value/54082731#54082731. I would suggest you duplicate your data and keep in your Firestore document a map or an array with **only** `nameL` values.